# Required SQL Query for not select some records in return results

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and am looking for a command that I want to use in a query, i want to query all the data from a table "EMPLOYEE" excluding some specific records which i want to not return in the result.

Comment: Use a WHERE clause: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)

Comment: I don't think this question meets minimum quality standards and as such shouldn't be migrated until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Super User!

Like Dr Moishe said, a WHERE statement is what you're looking for.  You'll be able to include and exclude specific column values. It would look something like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM FooTable WHERE Col1 = "This" AND Col2 != 4
```

Stack Overflow is a great resource for programming questions.

Comment: `"This"` is a column identifier - string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. `'This'`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *

FROM EMPLOYEE

WHERE *ROLES* **NOT IN** (*'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'*)

- The above query is using specific values in column example "roles" as filters.
- IN() allows you to include/exclude a group of values from results.

Answer (score -1):

As said already, a WHERE clause is required.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ is a great place to start out with SQL.